# robotframework - get all the variables/arguments passed to an execution

Tags: robotframework

Is there a way to access all the variables/arguments passed through the command line or variable file (-V option) during robotframework execution.  I know in python the execution can access it with 'sys.args' feature.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for getting the CLI arguments is inside your question - just look at the content of the `sys.argv`, you'll see everything that was passed to the executor:

```
${args}=        Evaluate    sys.argv        sys
Log To Console      ${args}
```

That'll return a list, where the executable itself (run.py) is the 1st member, and all arguments and their values present the in the order given during the execution:

```
['C:/my_directories/rf-venv/Lib/site-packages/robot/run.py', '--outputdir', 'logs', '--variable', 'USE_BROWSERSTACK:true', '--variable', 'IS_DEV_ENVIRONMENT:false', '--include', 'worky', 'suites\\test_file.robot']
```

You explicitly mention variable files; that one is a little bit trickier - the framework parses the files itself, and creates the variables according to its rules. You naturally can see them in the CLI args up there, and the other possibility is to use the built-in keyword [Get Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Variables), which "*Returns a dictionary containing all variables in the current scope.*" (quote from its documentation). Have in mind though that these are all variables - not only the passed on the command line, but also the ones defined in the suite/imported keywords etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have `Log Variables` to see their names and values "at current scope".

There is no possibility to see the arguments passed to robot.